# Bootstrapping: resampling cases vs resampling residuals

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, bootstrap, regression-coefficients

I have this relatively small dataset (41 observations, 5 independent and 1 dependent variable) and built a linear regression model with interaction terms.
Now I want to put confidence intervals around my coefficients.

At first, I created them based on the std. error estimate of my OLS-Regression (similar std. errors for each coefficient, around 0.19).
But then I noticed that my residuals are far from being normally distributed, which (afaik) affects the estimation of confidence intervals.

That's why I wanted to try bootstrapping but I am stuck on which method to use.

```
library(car)
Boot(model, R=1000, method="residual") #OR:
Boot(model, R=1000, method="case")
```

In general, the case-based bootstrapping appears to be more common and safer, because it doesn't make any assumptions about the distribution.
But the residual method does seem to be what I want, because it does only assume that my model fits the general shape of function (which is what I assume, or else I wouldn't do this...) but doesn't make any assumptions about the residuals (which is what I am worried about).

Comparing both outputs, the case-based bootstrapping returns estimated std. errors at around ~1.0 for my coefficients, residual-based bootstrapping only ~0.23, which is way closer to my original (presumably inflated) estimate.

So I am looking for advice on which method to trust and/or what other options I could try.
Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Case based bootstrap is less sensitive to departures from the form of the model.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the comment. What I am looking for is some kind of formal way to make that decision. How do I measure whether or not the form of my model fits well enough? Do i just decide based on measures of fit like r-squared, or are there any bootstrap specific ways to make that decision? The case based results differ enormously from the residual based ones

Comment: I found another helpful explanation of residual-based bootstrap as being applicable when we can assume our combinations of independent variables to be "fixed" for multiple re-runs, but where the outcome might vary (example: experiments with well defined conditions). This is the case for my data, so I will probably go with res.-based bootstrap (unless I get more answers ;) ). [page 13 of: https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Bootstrapping.pdf ]